# How to implement NSGraphicsContext in iphone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

```
CGContextRef ctx;

NSGraphicsContext *nsGraphicsContext;

nsGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext 
graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:NO];

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nsGraphicsContext];
```

There is no NSGraphicsContext for iphone.

Thus CGContextRef context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ....do i use this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hi... st3fan...

I am beginner in developer world.

Actually i am doing smudge effect on UIImageView.

I do have smudge effect for mac.  Now I am porting into iphone.

i find NSGraphicsContext in mac. 

Instead NSGraphicsContext can i use CGContextRef in my smudge Application? 

I found only few API do have in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you may use `UIGraphics*` for a handful of high level CGContext calls. otherwise, use the CoreGraphics APIs after accessing the current context object as you've outlined in your op. the CG-APIs are generally lower level, more detailed, task specific, can be less convenient than their Cocoa adaptations, but they are generally more thorough and provide more options.

CG-APIs are a good route to take (even on OS X) if you have moderate or complex rendering to perform. added bonus: you can often accomplish more on secondary threads using CG-APIs.